# Javascript Regex for a partial string match only

Tags: javascript, regex, string, match, partial

I need to write a JavaScript RegEx that matches only the partial strings in a word.

For example if I search using the string 'atta'

it should return

```
true for khatta
true for attari
true for navrattan
false for atta
```

I am not able to figure how to get this done using one RegEx. Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You want to use a non-word boundary `\B` here.

```
/\Batta|atta\B/
```

Comment: I think this is a much cleaner answer than mine

Comment: Good one. I may add that for `test` the capturing group is useless and memory consuming. I wonder if `!/\batta\b/.test(string)` isn't any faster...

Comment: @MaxArt would that not also match "foobar"?  If you're really worried about capturing groups, use a non-capturing group: `/(?:\Batta|atta\B)/`

Comment: I believe `!/\batta\b/.test(string)` will return true for "this too". I need a partial match at least.

Comment: Yep, `/\batta\b/` would match strings that also don't contain "atta" at all - I guess OP doesn't want that. @LeeKowalkowski There's no need to have groups either, in this case.

Comment: @MaxArt oh how right you are!  I seemed to have thought the brackets were always required for `|`.  I will edit my answer (and a few regexes I have lying around ha ha)

Answer (score 2):

sp00m almost got it right

```
^(atta.+|.+atta|.+atta.+)$
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vmvn8/).

If whitespace is not allowed you could write

```
^(atta[\S]+|[\S]+atta|[\S]+atta[\S]+)$
```

Comment: Or even `^(atta.+|.+atta.*)$` ;)

Comment: Hmm...so `atta` gives false but `atta ` gives true.